# What is the solution to the error "The value of type [User] 'cannot be converted to the expected argument type' User"?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

In my page named service, xcode points to the user and gives an error. but it doesn't work. What do you think should I change?
my user is already optional. I think it is an index problem but I don't know how to solve it I would appreciate it if you could help.where do you think the problem

message.swift

```
import Firebase

struct Message {
    let text: String
    let toId: String
    let fromId: String
    var timestamp: Timestamp!
    var user: User?
    let isFromCurrentUser :Bool
    
    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.text = dictionary["text"] as? String ?? ""
        self.toId = dictionary["toId"] as? String ?? ""
        self.fromId = dictionary["fromId"] as? String ?? ""
        self.timestamp = dictionary["timestamp"] as? Timestamp ?? Timestamp(date: Date())
        self.isFromCurrentUser = fromId == Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    }
    
    
}

struct Conversation {
    let user: User
    let message : Message
}
```

Service.Swift

```
import Firebase
 
struct Service  {
    static func  fetchUsers (completion: @escaping([User]) -> Void) {
        var users = [User] ()
       COLLECTION_USERS.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            snapshot?.documents.forEach({ (document) in
               
                let dictionary  = document.data()
                let user = User(dictionary: dictionary)
                users.append(user)
                completion(users)
            
            })
        }
    }
    
    static func fetchUser(widhtUid uid: String, completion:@escaping([User]) ->Void) {
        
COLLECTION_USERS.document(uid).getDocument { (snapshot, error) in
    guard let dictionary = snapshot?.data() else {return}
    let user = User(dictionary: dictionary)
    completion(user)
        }
        
        
    }
    
    
    static func fetchConversations (completion: @escaping([Conversation]) ->Void) {
        var conversations = [Conversation]()
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
        
        let query = COLLECTION_MESSAGES.document(uid).collection("recent-messages").order(by:  "timestamp")
        query.addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
            snapshot?.documentChanges.forEach({ change in
                let dictionary = change.document.data()
                let message = Message(dictionary: dictionary)
                
                self.fetchUser(widhtUid: message.toId) { user in
                    let conversation = Conversation(user:user, message: message)
                    conversations.append(conversation)
                    completion(conversations)
                }
                
           
            })
        }
        
    }
    
    
    static func fetchMessages    (forUser user: User, completion: @escaping([Message])-> Void)  {
    var messages  = [Message]()
    guard let currentUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
        let query = COLLECTION_MESSAGES.document(currentUid).collection(user.uid).order(by: "timestamp")
        query.addSnapshotListener{(snapshot,error) in
        snapshot?.documentChanges.forEach({ change in
            if change.type == .added {
                let dictionary = change.document.data ()
                
                messages.append(Message(dictionary: dictionary))
                completion(messages)
            }
        
            
            
            
        })
    }
    }
 static func  uploadMessage(message: String, to user: User, completion: ((Error?)->Void)?) {
        guard let currentUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
        let data = ["text": message,
                    "fromId": currentUid,
                    "toId": user.uid,
                    "timestamp" : Timestamp(date: Date())] as [String : Any]
           COLLECTION_MESSAGES.document(currentUid).collection(user.uid).addDocument(data:data) { _ in
                COLLECTION_MESSAGES.document(user.uid).collection(currentUid).addDocument(data:data,completion:completion)
            
            COLLECTION_MESSAGES.document(currentUid).collection("recent- messages").document(user.uid).setData(data)
            
            COLLECTION_MESSAGES.document(user.uid).collection("recent- messages").document(currentUid).setData(data)
            
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What line generates the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this method:

```swift
static func fetchUser(widhtUid uid: String, completion:@escaping ([User]) -> Void)
```

The completion closure's parameter should be a `User`, not an array of users - `[User]`.

Comment: You say is true, it fixed this mistake.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Xcode should point you to the line where this error happens...

Anyway, here

```
static func fetchUser(widhtUid uid: String, completion:@escaping([User]) ->Void) {
        
COLLECTION_USERS.document(uid).getDocument { (snapshot, error) in
    guard let dictionary = snapshot?.data() else {return}
    let user = User(dictionary: dictionary)
    completion(user)
        }
        
        
    }
```

Your `completion:@escaping([User]) ->Void)` expects an array [User] , but you invoke it with just one `User` object here `completion(user)`

Comment: True... I didn't find the opposite case though, so maybe thats a question typo :)

Comment: yes i got it i found my error thanks The user is not a user string, fixed when removing from array